# Why is e.user empty in the Google Spreadsheet simple trigger onOpen(e)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With the following code

```
function onOpen(e) {
  Logger.log(e.user);
  Logger.log(e.source);
  Logger.log(e.authMode);
}
```

I get the following logs if I reload the Spreadsheet:

---

[16-09-30 12:05:18:915 EDT]

[16-09-30 12:05:18:917 EDT] Spreadsheet

[16-09-30 12:05:18:919 EDT] LIMITED

---

From the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), I can't figure out why user would be empty when I reload the page - especially because I am signed in [image of me signed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXE1s.png)

Comment: Take a look at those restrictions: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()]

Comment: Try adding an onedit trigger to the same function and see if it logs the user.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside `onOpen(e)`:

1. Make sure that you're using a [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script). From your spreadsheet, Tools -> Script editor..
   I don't think `e.user` works on standalone scripts.
2. Use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` as another alternative.

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I verified that I am already using a bound script. 

When using Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() I get erratic behavior depending on the account/computer combination that is used, but I guess I'll have to accept that and move on.

Thanks for the help. I think we found the best solution available through Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), though it is not a resolved issue on my end

Comment: I managed to make it work, it should work fine with you also :) Dont forget to upvote/accept if the answer helped. cheers!